# Bullet doesn't fire towards expected direction

Tags: game-engine

I'm making an FPS game with blender and I can't get my bullet to fire in the right direction. Here's a link to the blend file https://mega.co.nz/#!AB1hSDob!sb_eL0uVHdRKFUwrG_74FjulLrU2gzRhIvrmXSOHYek

Any help would be awesome. This is all a learning experience for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix this problem by checking one button.

[image]

very simply, your bullet is always firing along one axis. When the "Local" box is clicked (the little square L) your bullet will fire along the local axis of the object that is emitting it.